# Xcode 6 UITableViewCell strange extra space at the top

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, xcode6

In Xcode 6 when I add new UITableViewCell some extra top padding adding automatically. I just found the solution how i can remove this padding programatically. But my question is for which purposes storyboard automatically add this padding?

As you can see on the picture below there is an extra white space between prototype cell and top border of the table that is selected right now.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? Can you post what have you made to fix it?

Comment: @NicosKaralis seems it's just like an storyboard issue. so on device it works ok

Answer (score 0):

You should disable "Adjust Scroll View Insets" from IB for that particular `UIViewController`.

[image]